# Is there a double role of "würde" in this sentence?

Tags: modal-verb

I just read the following sentence in a Swiss online newspaper:

> Ich habe der Finanzmarktaufsicht und der Schweizerischen Nationalbank geglaubt, dass der Werkzeugkasten in einer Krise angewendet und funktionieren würde.

Do I understand correctly, that *würde* is functioning both in a passive and an active voice here? If yes, is this common?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

I wouldn't say, it is very common. From a stylist point of view, one could consider it a stylistic flaw. But then, most native speakers (probably including the author themselves) would not even notice it.